# Dificuldades em Carregar dados no Input via Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou tentando carregar dados via Ajax ao digitar um código e clicar em TAB ele busca automaticamente no BD e imprime em inputs do form.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz um teste com o `console.log(data)` e os dados estão sendo retornados mas não carrega nos **Inputs** do formulario

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o Código JS

```
// Busco a Chave de Acesso
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#chave_acesso").change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            headers: Alvo.header(),
            dataType: 'json',
            url:  "{{$urlApiSearchKey}}"+ this.value + "",



            success: function(data) {


                console.log(data);


                $('#obs_nota').val(data.obs_nota);
                $('#pedido').val(data.pedido);

                $('#tipo').val(data.tipo);


            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Código não encontrado!"); },

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Adicione a parte pertinente ao html, e o print da parte do objeto onde está obs_nota, pedido e tipo...

Comment: o print acima é resultado do console.log(data)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo print postado na pergunta, o JSON retornado está vindo aninhado e o bloco `data:` é um subitem.

Neste caso, para pegar os valores, você terá que usar `data` 2x:

```
$('#obs_nota').val(data.data.obs_nota);
$('#pedido').val(data.data.pedido);
$('#tipo').val(data.data.tipo);
```

O 1º `data` do retorno do Ajax e o 2º do subitem do JSON.

Comment: Show @dvd deu certo!!